# How to make TouchableOpacity onlongPress custom duration

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I would like to make TouchableOpacity to fire event after 5seconds of pressing....
Is there a way to make a custom duration?

Comment: Is this answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this prop:

delayLongPress={5000}

Comment: it's not working for me. I ma using "react-native": "0.63.2". am i missing anything?